# Is a bad practice to use instance variable in a module?

Tags: ruby, module

I have a class `Foo` that uses a module `Bar`:

```
class Foo
  include Bar

  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end
end

module Bar
  def something
    @a + 1
  end
end
```

Is it a bad practice? Should it rather be like this?

```
module Bar
  def something(a)
    a + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instance variables in modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478747/instance-variables-in-modules)

Comment: @Sisyphe No, it is not a duplicate. Your linked question asks why it is possible in the first place. The current question asks whether it is recommended to put that into practice.

Comment: There's a third option: `a + 1` with `a` being a method that `Foo` has to implement, e.g. via `attr_reader :a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that `Bar` is highly coupled to the implementation of `Foo` if it uses a variable defined in `Foo`. What if there is no `@a` defined, or worse still it it defined but has a different purpose.

What if another class, say `Baz`, includes `Bar` and it renames `@a` to something more descriptive, then we also need to change `Bar` and thus we also need to change every other class which includes `Bar` too.

The module can expect the class it is included in to provide an interface, i.e. a set of methods. But this, again, this is coupling. But this is better than relying on `@a` variables. The interface can be defined, tested and documented. See [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Ruby).

There is a saying, "program to interfaces not implementations", from the GOF book. Here is an [interview](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) describing it.

Ideally a module adds behaviour to a class without any care for the kind of class it is included in.

It is hard to say what the best approach would be without a concrete example.

Comment: It's quite usual to have some kind of interface / requirement. `Enumerable` depends on `each`, `Comparable` depends on `<=>` and so on. A module without any coupling whatsoever should probably define its methods as class methods or as [module functions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function).

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to express the spectrum of coupling, I think of some better wording.