# Unable to set session in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here is the file I am trying to test

```
module Cesid
  module Access
    def cesid_signout
      return unless session_logged
      
      # Method to modify the cookie 
      set_cookie
    end

    def session_logged
      session[:cesid_logged]
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my rspec file

```
describe Cesid::Access do
  context '#cesid_signout' do
    let!(:access) { Class.new { extend Cesid::Access } }
    it 'does nothing if not cesid logged' do
      session[:cesid_logged] = false
      expect(access.session_logged).to eql(false)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just getting an error after running the rspec. The logs just keep printing this and I can't view this first line of the error

```
# /Users/renee.sarmiento/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@ls-member/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_process.rb:14:in `session'
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all the context in your use case.

But it is clear that you don't have access to `session` into your cached variable `access` since `session` is not an instance variable.

So I suggest two things:

- First, make sure that you can initiate your `session` instance variable into your module [as explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478747/instance-variables-in-modules)

```rb
module Cesid
  module Access
    def cesid_signout
      return unless session_logged

      # Method to modify the cookie
      set_cookie
    end

    def session
      @session ||= {}
    end

    def session_logged
      @session[:cesid_logged]
    end
  end
end
```

- Then, in your spec, make sure not only to instantiate your session but also access it the right way :

```rb
context '#cesid_signout' do
  let!(:access) { Class.new { extend Cesid::Access } }

  it 'does nothing if not cesid logged' do
    access.session[:cesid_logged] = false
    expect(access.session_logged).to eql(false)
  end
end
```

With those modification, your RSpec tests should pass.

Of course it is one way to solve your problem, but depending on your use case, other solution might work.

Hope it'll help your understanding.
More insight of how module works [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html) just in case.